Is there an easy way to remove unwanted dependencies from the Chromium repository?
I’m working on building a lightweight version of Chromium. I want to exclude unnecessary dependencies, such as the support for iOS, Android, ChromeOS, Chromecast, etc.
What steps should I take to modify the underlying code to identify and remove what I do not want?
So far, I have a working build of the browser. I’ve tried configuring gclient like this:
solutions = [
    { "name"        : 'src',
      "url"         : 'https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git',
      "deps_file"   : 'DEPS',
      "managed"     : False,
      "custom_deps" : {
          "src/third_party/catapult": None,
          "src/third_party/devtools-frontend": None,
          "src/third_party/ffmpeg": None,
          "src/third_party/libjingle": None,
          "src/third_party/widevine": None,
          "src/chrome/android": None,
          "src/ios": None,
          "src/chromeos": None,
          "src/components/cast_channel": None,
      },
      "custom_vars": {},
    },
]


Update; the deleting dependencies portion of this link is helpful.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/dependencies.md

I wouldn't recommend doing so. Chromium repo uses a single source code for all the platforms. There are too many dependencies and shared code.
